# Python to .exe --> no module named numpy

Tags: python

as understandable from the title, I converted a .py into .exe using pyinstaller, now that I am trying running it it tells me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PredictiveDemand_Final_V2.0.3_SQL.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Needless to say I import numpy in my code. Before importing numpy I also import pandas but that does not seem to be a problem.

Thanks

Comment: @Sphinx  I don't know what you mean by that. Would you mind explaining?Please

Comment: Have you installed the numpy module on your machine? If you have pip installed, it's as simple as running "pip install numpy" from your command line.

Comment: Well, yes, numpy is installed on my machine so it should run without any problem.. also.. I use numpy in my code so that means it is installed. The reason I converted it into an .exe is because I want it to run on pc that don't have Python

Comment: That is not correct. Just because you reference a numpy module in your code does not mean the package is installed. I would uninstall numpy and reinstall it with pip.

Comment: I need to correct myself. I took numpy out and it's giving me the same problem with pandas

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding your executable, but have a closer look at the warnings while building, pyinstaller ignores the modules which it can't and gives a warning.

if that doesn't work, you try

1. reinstalling the numpy, and then build the exec.
2. or use --hidden-import option for building exec.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with pandas so I guess I'll try option 2. Also, --hidden-import is a function of pyinstaller?? When you say look for warnings, I tried but nothing seemed to say 'not importing modules etc etc'

Comment: You were right. When converting to .exe pyinstaller is missing all the modules. Could you expand on the --hidden-import option please?

Comment: --hidden-import is used when there is an implicit import, and pyinstaller is unable to detect the import.

*one advice is to use pyinstaller in a fresh environment (virtualenv, etc I use a docker container) this will resolve the dependency issues also reducing the size of your package.